# How to find out when empty repository was created?

Tags: github

I have a repository in GitHub that is empty and I want to find out when it was created. Is it possible somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access it by Github API https://api.github.com/repos/%7Busername%7D/%7Brepository%7D and look at created_at parameter there.